# xamarin iOS non dismissible local notifications

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a client that wants to have a local notification that the user can not dismiss and will be there until the app is closed. I can get this to work in android but not in iOS. I am working in xamarin and have had to break out of the pcl to accomplish this and the notifications in general. Is this something that can be accomplished(does apple allow this)? Or is a widget extension what I am in need of creating?

Answer (score 0):

You can present a local notification on top of your running app
by implementing `IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and calling the `WillPresentNotification` completionHandler with the  `UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert` option.

**But** you can not prevent the user from dismissing it, thus is would be cleared from the Notification Center.

I'm not sure what information you are trying to show in the "permanent" notification, but it sounds like a Today View Widget is something you should look at. The downside of course is Today widgets require that the user manually adds the widget to the Today view and depending upon your needs that they enabled it for lock screen usage.

Here is how you would do a local notification and make it present itself on top of your app....

#### Implement IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate:

```
[Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
{
     completionHandler.DynamicInvoke( UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert );
}
```

#### Assign the UNUserNotificationCenter Delegate:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
```

#### Send a local notification:

```
var unAuthorizationOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert & UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge & UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
var authReply = await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorizationAsync(unAuthorizationOptions);
if (authReply.Item1 == true) // Xamarin.iOS does not label the tuple members ;-( (granted, error) 
{
    var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent
    {
        Title = "Local Notification",
        Subtitle = "By SushiHangover",
        Body = "StackOverflow rocks",
        Badge = badgecount
    };
    var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier("SushiHangover", content, null);
    await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequestAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: The app is collecting gps location info and the client wants to have the notification/widget so they can see the info at a glance without going into the app. Thanks for the help I will look into the today widget and see about that. I think that is the route that I need to go. again thanks for the input.