# Should not be swipe out the notification for iOS using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.Forms. I want the notification on notification bar not to be swiped out on both Android and iOS. For Android, I am using `SetOnGoing(true)` on notification builder. However, I cannot achieve that one on iOS. I am using the following override method on iOS:

```
public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
{
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't implement the same functionality on iOS. Android is much more flexible on how the notifications can be handled by the developer but for iOS, only internal apps developed by Apple (and those who have special permissions to call internal API's) can do what you're attempting.

---

**Edit:** What you can try, is to work around this limitation by creating a Today widget as [suggested by SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45949304/6625726) a couple of years ago.